# How can injections from a "bigger" space to a "smaller" one exist?

Tags: geometry

I have this question about injective functions that I can't answer. Take the top half of the sphere $S^2$ and the disc $D^2$ and  as an example. The "vertical" projection from the former to the latter is an injection.

It seems counterintuitive to me that such an injection can exist, when the area of the upper hemisphere is greater than that of the disc, i.e. the upper hemisphere consists of more points than the disc. Which property of the space $R^3$ that can answer this question am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Injection do not preserve area. In particular, $$A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2: (x,y) \mapsto (2x, 2y)$$ is a bijection, but clearly doesn't preserve area.

In a set theoretical point of view, the upper hemisphere and disc contain an equal amount of points (i.e. the same amount as $\mathbb{R}$ does). The proper 'counting intuition' rules do not carry over wholesale here.

Another example is the fact that there exists an injection from $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{N}$, while intuitively you'd estimate $\mathbb{Q}$ to be much larger.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the comment that those surfaces contain the same amount of points?

Comment: By definition, two sets have the same amount of points if a bijection exists between them. Since you gave a bijection, by definition they have the same amount of points.

Comment: The problem here is that the *measure* is not preserved - the image of a surface element of the hemisphere with area 1 won't have area 1. However, this is a more complicated concept than the number of points in a set.